# Change model value on hover of div element in emberjs

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I am trying to create a component some thing like list view where each item is a div. On hover of an item it gets highlighted and also 2 icons should appear, for these icons to appear I can monitor model variable and change class accordingly. Is this correct thought process, or is there a simpler way.

At present I am unaware on how to change model variable on hover over div element. Please help in either of 2 mentioned ways

1. Help in changing model variable on hover over div element
2. Is there a better way to do this kind of work in emberjs?

list-view.hbs

```
<div class="listViewContainer">
    <div class="dropdown ulContainer">
      {{#each data as |item|}}
        <div class="listItem row">
            <div class="message col-md-10">
                {{#if (eq dataCount 2)}}
                    <span class="counter">{{item.doc_count}}</span>{{item.key}}
                {{else}}
                    {{item.key}}
                {{/if}}
            </div>            
            <div class="actions col-md-2">
                <img src="assets/images/filter_add.svg" class="" {{action "toggleFilterCollapsed"}} width="25px" height="25px"/>
                {{#if settingsNeeded}}
                    <img class="actionsCol" src="assets/images/action_menu.svg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Action" alt="Action" {{action '' item.key}}/>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="divider"/>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listViewContainer {
    text-align: left;
    .ulContainer {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 2em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .listItem:hover { 
        background-color:#E2F1FD; 
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        border: 1px solid #71B8FF;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .listItem {
        padding: 5px;
        list-style-position: inside;
        list-style: none;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .counter {
        font-family: $app-font;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-right: 18px;
    }
    .message {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .actions {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .divider {
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border-top: none;       
    }       
    .actionsCol {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.2;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
}
```

**Current view screenshot**
[image]

**The desired outcome needed**
[image]

Comment: First thought is why not just use a CSS-only solution with a `:hover` rule?

Comment: @SteveH. How would I use a `:hover` rule on parent div element of the icons, so that the hover properties of icons also gets affected? Can you please share an example which I can view and make use of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter child's CSS on parent CSS by placing child element inside parent's hover rule.

In your case make display property of `actions` CSS class to none and add `display: none` property to `actions` CSS class inside `.listItem:hover`. Given below all changes.

```
.listItem:hover { 
    background-color:#E2F1FD; 
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    border: 1px solid #71B8FF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    .actions {
        display: block;
    }
}
...
.actions {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: ? How does this change the data?